# What's the ultimate objective of photography?

Tags: photography-basics, art

What is the ultimate objective of artistic  photography? (Let's exclude photography for journalism.) My understanding is that the objective is to make an emotional impact on the viewer.  I could also see that the photographers themselves also gain some satisfaction. But isn't that a by-product and not the primary purpose?

Comment: Related: [Does every interesting photograph have a story to tell?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/84215/15871) and [How to know whether you are good in photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90017/15871) and [What makes a photo a good photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2296/15871)

Comment: Kiran, while there is an inherent subjectivity to photography, and while we do want to encourage questions about the artistic and other more subjective aspects of photography, I am sorry to say, this particular question is both overly broad and much too subjective. I appreciate the effort to bring more art-side photography questions into play here, truly! Please do not let the closure of this question discourage you from continuing to ask about those aspects of photography. All we ask is, try to word them so they fit with the format of stack exchange, and so they are answerable. Thanks!

Comment: The question incorrectly presupposes a single common "ultimate objective," and that false premise makes the question unanswerable. Different photographers have different goals: to influence; to entertain; to express; to earn a living; to document; to question; to educate; to unite; to amuse; to shock; and so on. To try to cover all those motivations in a single expression is to dilute them into something meaningless.

Comment: @Caleb - that could, in itself be an answer.

Comment: @AJHenderson Maybe, but *here's why the question is unanswerable* is more a reason to close than an answer IMO.

Comment: @Caleb - perhaps, but I'd say "the ultimate objective depends on the individual" is an easily supportable subjective answer.  Simply give a few distinct cases of how different artists had vastly different objectives and you've supported the answer.  Explaining fundamental problems with a question can be an answer to the question as the point is to gain further understanding and the answer addresses the understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to avoid talking about the goal of art overall — partly because I think that's explored nicely at [What makes "fine art" fine art?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10928/what-makes-fine-art-fine-art/10936#10936), but also because the specific question of the  of *the role photography as an artistic medium* has a definitive answer.

In fact, let's take for granted the broader, general notions of "what is art?" — art as communication, art as emotion, art as conversation, art as creation, art as provocation, whatever. Yes, sure. But *photography as a medium is in service of all of that*. We don't need to argue about what exactly "all that" is, because even when people disagree, it can all be right.

However, when we talk about different media, these actually have different real and physical properties. Sculpture is about form in space, and may be about the properties of stone, wood, metal. Pen and ink is about lines, modeling, and texture. Textile art is about fibers and colors and draping and weight. Art can fulfill all of the big ideas that make it art *without* attempting to be true to these — but following the nature of the medium opens up another facet, and that's the aspect that's interesting to concentrate on here.

So, photography! Fundamentally, *this* medium is about **drawing with light captured from the reflection of the object itself**. This gives it a connection with reality that's different from all other visual arts — this, along with a **highly mechanical nature** makes [nature printing](http://www.lib.udel.edu/ud/spec/exhibits/color/natures.htm) in some ways a closer cousin than other two-dimensional visual arts like drawing or painting.

The photographic process and the nature of the camera — a **light-proof box with an aperture** — provide unique limitations which form the backbone of the photographic language. Photographs:

- **Distill** the **time** of capture, whether a short exposure or long, to a single, unified still image. They distort motion, by freezing or blurring it.
- **Reduce** three-dimensional **space** to a flat frame, with perspective, focus, and depth of field frozen in a way that's all to do with optics and nothing to do with an omniscient observer's perception of form.
- **Select** a narrow field of **view**, providing a narrow window onto the world.
- **Set color and key** in a fixed way, removing the human vision system's natural accommodations for changing light.

Altogether, photography involves an intentional distillation from reality to image through a bounded mechanical process. John Szarkowski identifies this as *the key unique element* of the art of photography, calling it "a process based not on synthesis but on selection" in the introduction to *[The Photographer's Eye](https://archive.org/details/JohnSzarkowskiThePhotographersEyeMuseumOfModernArt2007/page/n5)*.

Art, of course, is not bound by these limitations, just as sculpture can incorporate found materials or ink drawings be combined with colors, but *art which is photography* is **art which works with, through, and *because of* the unique elements of the medium**. Likewise, the objective of photography as art is to use this medium in the strongest way possible to accomplish the larger goals of the artist, *whatever those are*.

Comment: "To photograph is to frame, and to frame is to exclude." - Susan Sontag from *Regarding the Pain of Others*. This goes right along with Szarkowski's statement that, I believe, distills the most fundamental nature of what a photograph is.

Answer (score 3):

If seen from the purist viewpoint: Making a somewhat permanent copy of the visual impression an incidental or staged scene provides, for aesthetic or emotional enjoyment of the result, enjoyment of the process of creating, or both. Focus is on the visual impression.

The counterpoint to this is what journalism, simple product photography, other documentary applications, keeping memories, pornography and other are about: Creating an incomplete but economical copy of the subject matter for information, documentation, communication, emotional usage - the focus is more on the subject matter here.

In practice, you will usually have a mix of both :)

Answer (score 2):

Specifically artistic photography? I would say that an image "succeeds" (fulfills its objective) when it is an image that someone wants to look at more than once. There are a multitude of reasons why an image might capture someone's attention like that -- from simple beauty, appreciation of technical merit, historical significance and so on. It might not be the original photographer who's attention is captured, for example, it seems likely that many of Vivian Maier's photographs were only appreciated after her death.

And, I suppose, that implied in "someone wants to look at more than once" is the idea that the more people who want to see it more than once makes an image "more successful" -- but I think using eyeballs as a measure of quality would fall apart after a while. At some point, you get millions of people looking at something *because* millions of people have looked at something.